# Baker Reliability index

Tags: baking, baking-rights

What is the formula for `Baker Reliability` index, how the index is calculated and what is the impact of the index?

I talk about https://tzstats.com/ page.

Comment: It depends on which site you have in mind, because different explorers calculate it differently. For example tzkt.io [shows it's own "Reliability" index](https://tzkt.io/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB/rewards) which differs from tzstats' one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This webpage](https://new.tezos-nodes.com/about) gives an explanation of the TzStats baker reliability index.

Comment: Is it your service? What are conditions to find some bankier in the list of bakers? I am not able to find some bakers.

Comment: No, I'm not affiliated with them. On the lower right of the webpage, you find several options for contacting them, e.g. email: support@tezos-nodes.com